# cakePHP validation

Tags: php, cakephp

I am working on a cakePHP project and have set up my data validation.  The problem i have is that i keep getting an error from the core/model of cakePHP.

The error is:
Notice (8): Undefined offset:  0 [CORE/cake/libs/model/model.php, line 2435]

```
                        if (is_array($validator['rule'])) {
                        $rule = $validator['rule'][0];
```

My validation rules look like this:

```
    var $validate = array(
    'name' => array(
        'rule' => array('maxLength' => 80),
        'required' => true,
        'message' => 'Please enter your name'
    ),
    'address1' =>  array(
        'rule' => array('maxLength' => 80),
        'required' => true,
        'message' => 'You forgot your address'
    ),
    'address2' =>  array(
        'rule' => array('maxLength' => 80),
        'message' => 'Your address can\'t be that long?'
    ),
    'city' =>  array(
        'rule' => array('maxLength' => 80),
        'required' => true,
        'message' => 'Your city can\'t be that long?'
    ),
    'zip' =>  array(
        'rule' => array('postal', null, 'us'),
        'required' => true,
        'message' => 'Your zip code is not in the corect format.'
    ),
    'phone' =>  array(
        'rule' => array('phone', null, 'us'),
        'required' => true,
        'message' => 'Your phone number is not in the corect format.'
    ),
    'email' => array(
        'rule' => 'email',
        'required' => true,
        'message' => 'Please enter a valid email address.'
    ),
    'seats' =>  array(
        'rule' => 'numeric',
        'required' => true,
        'message' => 'You forgot to let us know how many seats you need.  If you will not be attending please enter a zero (0)'
    ),
    'seat_with' => array(   
        'rule' => array('maxLength' => 80),
        'message' => 'Please keep this field below 80 charcters.'
    ),
    'cc_name' =>  array(
        'rule' => array('maxLength' => 80),
        'required' => true,
        'message' => 'Did you forget something?'
    ),
    'cc_number' => array(
        'rule' => array('cc', 'all', false, null),
        'required' => true,
        'message' => 'Your credit card number is not in the correct format.'
    ),
    'cc_expiration' => array(
        'rule' => array('date', 'my'),
        'required' => true,
        'message' => 'The correct answer will be in the following format MM/YYYY'
    ),
    'cc_cvv' => array(
        'rule' => 'numeric',
        'required' => true,
        'message' => 'Numbers only please.'
    )
    );
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your problem is in the rule syntax:

> ```
> array('maxLength' => 80)
> ```

Just like your other rules, it's `,`, not `=>`: `array('maxLength', 80)`.

---

BTW, my city *can* be that long: [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krung Thep Mahanakhon Amon Rattanakosin Mahinthara...](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krung_Thep_Mahanakhon_Amon_Rattanakosin_Mahinthara_Yuthaya_Mahadilok_Phop_Noppharat_Ratchathani_Burirom_Udomratchaniwet_Mahasathan_Amon_Piman_Awatan_Sathit_Sakkathattiya_Witsanukam_Prasit) ;-)

Comment: Exactly what i needed.  What a noob mistake thanks deceze.  I will also increase the size of the city name. =)

Comment: While you're at it, you might correct the spelling of "corect" to "correct" in the messages for "zip" and "phone". :)